# Download blob never each 100%

Tags: javascript

I have a web based file repository where the files are stored as Base64 in IndexebDB. The page is offline based and used on vessels with poor or no internet connection.

For some reason, the download never ends, causing the file extension to stay as .crdownload and file cannot be opened. This does not happen on my PC with good internet, but I'm not sure why that should matter

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
var isBlob = input instanceof Blob;
var uri = isBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(input) : input;
    
link.href = uri;
link.download = filename;

document.body.appendChild(link);

link.click();


setTimeout(() => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(uri);
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}, 100);
```

[image: Never ending download]

Comment: You are removing the link (I guess that `a` is `link`) after 100ms. Could it be that the download has not finished yet when deleting the element? You could increase the remove time to test this.

Comment: it's more likely that `window.URL.revokeObjectURL(uri);` is the culprit rather than `document.body.removeChild(a);` ... since `a` is `undefined`, that statement does nothing anyway

Comment: Changing to 1000ms still same issue. Commenting the whole "remove all" away does nothing. Still not 100% completion

Comment: I have removed the security setting for Chrome and it works fine. I have standard, and perhaps that is the problem? It cannot verify blob content somehow? Setting it to no protection all works out well

Comment: @JaromandaX I expected that `a` is a typo and that `a` should have actually been `link`.  That's what I meat with "I guess that `a` is `link`". Removing an `undefined` obviously doens't change anything :D

Comment: Does it work on stable internet connection?

Comment: Yes, stable connection, or even NO connection works great. So if they physically pulls the plug it will work

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a `resume` function in your code, also made the code more robust, try this out and see if it will work:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var link = document.createElement('a');
var isBlob = input instanceof Blob;
var uri = isBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(input) : input;
var fileSize = isBlob ? input.size : null;
var downloadedBytes = 0;

link.download = filename;
document.body.appendChild(link);

xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

// Check if the file already exists and set the starting offset for resuming the download
if (fileSize && localStorage.getItem(filename)) {
  downloadedBytes = localStorage.getItem(filename);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=' + downloadedBytes + '-' + fileSize);
}

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 206) {
    var blob = xhr.response;

    if (downloadedBytes === 0) {
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    } else {
      // Append the downloaded bytes to the partially downloaded file
      var prevBlob = new Blob([localStorage.getItem(filename), blob]);
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(prevBlob);
    }

    // Save the current downloaded bytes to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem(filename, downloadedBytes + blob.size);

    // Trigger the download
    link.click();

    // Clean up resources
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(uri);
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  // Handle error
};

xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
  // Update the downloadedBytes variable as the download progresses
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    downloadedBytes = e.loaded;
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: I will try this but the issue is not that the file is not being downloaded. All bytes are downloaded, but it does not change file extension. The file size is 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

You Could **Refresh Your** Downloads Folder or you can just change, the Extension
from **".crdownload"** to **".docx"**. Hope That helps.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not helpful since I cannot instruct my end users to do this. It must be fixed automatic